# Crashe Application when create Object of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a project that uses crystal report 11.5 Designer And Viewer in vb.net.
both of them (Designer And Viewer) work currectly when executed separately.
but when execute following commands are executed in a row, my app is crashed
-- RepDoc = New ReportDocument
-- objCrystalApp = New CRAXDDRT.Application
please help me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will put the code for you to better understand. Please run the following code

Comment: Private Sub Frm_Main_Test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim My_CrystalApp As New CRAXDDRT.Application
        Dim My_RepDoc As New ReportDocument
    End Sub